# The best case for my algorithm is n=1 because that is the fastest? is it correct?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Best case is defined as which input of size n is cheapest among all inputs of size n.
“The best case for my algorithm is n=1 because that is the fastest.”? Is it right or wrong? If i give input N of large size, its mean it will take extra time. if i give input of smaller N value, its mean it will take less time? So, its mean we are dependent on the size of input..? and, if i give input any number(like 45) for the N size array for searching, and element found at the end, its also mean worst case? (but where from N comes? is it already fixed? )
I am confused about all this? If i consider both cases. mean,

1. We will fix the size of array like N, I made an array of N items
2. We will put an element as input for search.

its mean, worst case, best case, average case, is dependent on both things that are mentioned above ( N size array, and type of input). 
am i right?

Comment: It all *depends*. Not algorithms' best case is for an input of size 1.

Answer (score 1):

n is fixed, you cannot set it to 1: "is cheapest among all inputs of size n". Best case and worst case depends only on the type of input, which must be of size n.

For example, if you do a linear search among n elements, the best case is if you find it immediately on first try, the worst case is if you have to look at all n elements.

Comment: "which must be of size n", No......, If i am searching, then it will always be size=1 , not size n.

Comment: This is from your own definition: "Best case is defined as which input of size n is cheapest among all inputs of size n." It means the input size is fixed at n.

Answer (score 1):

Well the thing is - it is not the number of input that is in case over here. Ofcourse if you sort one element then it will be best. If you search in one element list then it will be faster. We generalize this notion keeping in mind that input is `n` - and it's fixed w.r.t to this analysis. We can't say that mergesort with 1 element is faster than quicksort with 2 elements. It's not a valid comparison. With this being said,

- Best case: A case for which it takes fastest time to complete, the conditions, the inputs all are perfect, optimal as expected by the algorithm.
- Worst case: The case when input is such that we will run into a higher time.
- Average case: Algorithm is run many times on different inputs (not saying that their size will be different - it won't. The size is fixed at `n`). And then we will take the average over all the running time. Take the average over all the inputs (of this given size `n`), weighted with probability distribution.

So to answer your question - it's the type of input that we talk about. The property of the input, for example:-

For quicksort best case is `O(nlongn)` worst case `O(n^2)` and average case is `O(nlogn)`. (Worst case appears when the pivot is being selected as first element of the numbers).

Take the idea, here for best case we are not considering the number of input. The best case of quicksort occurs when the pivot we pick happens to divide the array into two exactly equal parts, in every step. Again you see number o inputs we are considering as `n`.

Check CLRS for getting the average case analysis. Solve the math or atleast try to. It's fun how you derive that.

Answer (score 0):

When it is stated that something is O(n), that means that the expected time is *proportional* to the number of elements in the input.  This means that if you double the input, then you double the expected time of the work.  An example of this is going through through an array element by element until you find the result.  Or adding all the elements of an array.

O(1) means that the function will take the same amount of time regardless of the amount of input.  You'll see this when looking up a value in a hash.  It is an indexed lookup, so it doesn't have to go through every element.

Something like O(n^2) means that the effort is proportional to the square of the number of elements involved.  You'll see this when running all the combinations of the elements.  So an array of 10 would provide 100 different possible inputs to a function with 2 parameters.

Searching an ordered array might be done in O(log(n)) because you can guess an element, then eliminate half and never have to search them.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to your algorithm. For example, if I want to use a element in an array, whatever your size is, it takes the same time. Because it's spend O(1) time. However, if you want to use an algorithm that takes O(N) time:

```
FindMaxElementInAnArray(A)
a=-∞
for each i in A
    if i>a
    a=i
return a
```

the bigger the array is, the slower the algorithms runs.
And there's a situation like this

```
SomeBoredPseudocode(A)
if(A.size()>100)
    error "oops, I don't need such a big array"
i=100;
if i==A.size()
    exit
else
    i=i-1
```

This one takes O(100-N) time.